# How to write model classes for Entity Framework Core matching this SQL table design

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to write model classes that reflect this SQL Server table design, so that the migration code based on these model classes recreates the tables in SQL Server:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ParentTable 
(
    ParentID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    UniColumn INT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE ChildTable 
(
    ChildID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (ChildID) REFERENCES ParentTable(UniColumn)
);
```

These tables **must** have exact same design, no different column names, no extra columns added.

So far these are my model classes:

```cs
[Index(nameof(UniColumn), IsUnique = true)]
public class ParentTable
{
    [Key]
    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UniColumn { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ChildTable> ChildTables { get; set; }
}

public class ChildTable
{
    [Key]
    public int ChildID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentTable")]
    public int UniColumn { get; set; }

    public ParentTable ParentTable { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, the migration code looks like this, foreign key constraint is coming from `ParentId` and not `UniColumn`, and `UniColumn` is added to `ChildTable`:

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "ParentTables",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ParentID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    UniColumn = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_ParentTables", x => x.ParentID);
                });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "ChildTables",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ChildID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    UniColumn = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_ChildTables", x => x.ChildID);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_ChildTables_ParentTables_UniColumn",
                        column: x => x.UniColumn,
                        principalTable: "ParentTables",
                        principalColumn: "ParentID",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_ChildTables_UniColumn",
                table: "ChildTables",
                column: "UniColumn");

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_ParentTables_UniColumn",
                table: "ParentTables",
                column: "UniColumn",
                unique: true);
```

How do I exactly match the original table design?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys ?

Comment: Scaffold + Create Initial migration?